# Visual SVN to display UserName instead of number in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server

Recently i setup VisualSVN Server Manager as my project svn server.

Can someone guide me how to configure the Eclipse to show the last changed author name instead of show last changed revision?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's plugin dependent. I'm using subclipse and the settings are available in Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> Label Decorations -> Text tab